# How to emulate ShellExecute() with CreateProcess()

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to open a `*.jpg` file with `CreateProcess()` and I want `CreateProcess()` to behave *exactly* the same as when opening the `*.jpg` with `ShellExecute()`.

So I first use `FindExecutable()` to get the viewer application for the `*.jpg` file, then I concatenate the viewer application's path and the path to the `*.jpg` file, adding quotes to make sure it works with paths that have spaces in them.

However, the result is not the same: On my system `*.jpg` files are associated with an application that has a lightweight viewer mode and a more sophisticated editor mode. When I use `ShellExecute()` to open the file (or double-click on it in Explorer), the viewer application opens in the lightweight viewer mode. When I use `CreateProcess()` as described above, however, the viewer application shows the `*.jpg` file as well but it opens in editor mode.

So `ShellExecute()` must be doing something else that causes the viewer application to behave like it does but I don't know what. Any ideas what might be missing to make `CreateProcess()` behave exactly like `ShellExecute()`?

This is what the code looks like currently:

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;

memset(&piProcInfo, 0, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));
memset(&siStartInfo, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));

siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO); 

CreateProcess(NULL, cmdline, NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &siStartInfo, &piProcInfo);
```

Comment: `ShellExecute` hosts *decades* of compatibility shims. Trying to replicate its behavior exactly is either near impossible, or not legal.

Comment: I might not even need to replicate its behaviour exactly, I was just wondering why the viewer application behaves like that and if there is a way to make it behave as if the file was started through `ShellExecute()`.

Comment: *"I want `CreateProcess()` to behave **exactly** the same as when opening the `*.jpg` with `ShellExecute()`."* - If you don't want that, don't ask for it. Anyway, I wouldn't be too surprised if `ShellExecute` has an internal list of applications to decide for the best fit, given equally fitting application matches.

Comment: *Why* do you can't use `ShellExecute` / `ShellExecuteEx`? What is the *actual* problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Actually, I can use `ShellExecute` but I was curious and was thinking that maybe there was just a flag or so that could be set to make `CreateProcess` behave like `ShellExecute` and I was missing out on that flag because `CreateProcess` has many options, but as it turns out, things are much more complex so I should better use `ShellExecute` I guess...

Comment: @zet: One reason to not use `ShellExecute[Ex]` would be, if you are calling it from a thread that is initialized into the multi-threaded apartment. Sure, this can be solved by throwing yet another thread at the problem, but that may not be feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ShellExecute` uses `CreateProcess` internally but before it gets there it does many other things.

[This blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160408-00/?p=93274) by Raymond Chen provides a hint:

> The Find­Executable function comes from 16-bit Windows, and back in those days, there were no **context menu shell extensions or custom drop targets**. (There was DDE, but that’s okay, because programs still have to register an executable to be used in the fallback case when nobody responds to the DDE message.)
>
> ...
>
> **Newer applications shouldn’t be using Find­Executable anyway, seeing as the handler for a file type may not even be an executable.**

A `IContextMenu` based shell extension could be the default and if it is, it can do anything and `ShellExecute` just tells the extension to invoke the command. This is not done if `SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST` is not specified?

A classic static verb in the registry can have [`IExecuteCommand`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100312-01/?p=14623) and/or drop target handlers that also perform the actual execution.

If neither of the above are true, `ShellExecute` will look for DDE registration and if found it will try to use DDE.

If all else fails, `ShellExecute` will use `CreateProcess` to invoke the command string after substituting the %1 values.

Even if you emulate all of this (including all the undocumented details and compatibility workarounds) you still have to call `ShellExecute` if the command resolves to a executable that requires UAC elevation.

Just figuring out which verb is the true default is hard enough, I suggest that you just use `ShellExecute` and let the shell handle the rest.

If you are just curious, you can look at the resulting command line in Task Manager or Process Explorer to see if a custom handler simply adds a special parameter.